# Encrypt SVN issue

Tags: linux, permissions, svn, password, encryption

could anyone advise how to encrypt SVN  , Plan to encrypt or disable the SVN from asking if unencrypted passwords should be stored? We never want a user to be able to do that.

Would encrypting the users' home directory to protect the passwords as well as the data work? If so, how to do that? what is the best approach here?

I was thinking of encrypting the password files and add these encrypted files to SVN.

```
svn, version 1.7.14 (r1542130)    compiled Oct  7 2020, 22:48:31

which svn
/bin/svn

whereis svn
svn: /usr/bin/svn /usr/share/man/man1/svn.1.gz
```

Is this approach solve my problem?

```
~/.subversion/servers:

[global]
# Password / passphrase caching parameters:
store-passwords = no
store-plaintext-passwords = no

[root@ip-10-0-16-165 auth]#

vi ~/.subversion/servers

[global]

store-passwords = yes

store-plaintext-passwords = no

In ~/.subversion/config

[auth]

store-passwords = yes

store-auth-creds = yes

password-stores = gnome-keyring , kwallet
```

what is the best approach here ?

Comment: What are you asking? There seems to be multiple topics, but no clear question here.

Comment: I want to Encrypt the SVN User group(devs), but unable to figure out which one would be best fit OpenSSH or  GNOME keyring solution, Are there any security issues with the GNOME keyring ? what is the best advise here ?